# bundle exec rake db:migrate -- schema.rb regenerated WITHOUT indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a large database with tons of tables and many indices on those tables. Every time I run a migration, the schema.rb file is generated fine, EXCEPT none of the indices are included. New tables and columns are added fine. If I manually re-add the add_index lines to the schema.rb file after the migration, it works fine, but doing this after every migration is a major hassle.

I've been dealing with this problem for months and haven't been able to find any solution or workaround. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Using Postgres & Rails 3.

Comment: you can try by generating a migration file just to add indeces to all your tables `add_index :users, [:email, :first_name, :last_name]` and so on..and run the migration

Comment: It appears that the indices are already on the tables (when i connect via psql and run '\d table_name'). But for some reason it's just never getting written into the schema.rb file.

Comment: FWIW, I tried running a migration with add_index and the resulting schema.rb file that was generated still did NOT contain the indices.

Comment: I assume you've looked in `config/application.rb`, your initializers, and your environment files for anything that stands out? If not, you would be looking for something like `config.active_record.something_about_schema`

Comment: @D-Nice It'd be easier to debug if we could see the schema and the migration.  Are you using add_index or index: true?  index: true works on references and belongs_to but not add_column.  add_index should generally work.  Can you share the schema and sample migrations?

Comment: @BigRon Yes, I've looked for these. Nothing suspicious in any of the project files

Comment: @R_G Well the problem is that the indices get wiped out regardless of what the migration is. I could be adding a new table with no add_index, and the new schema.rb would erase all the old indices. However, when I psql into the database I see that the indices actually exist. So it's as if Rails isn't seeing the postgres indices when it re-generates the schema.rb.

Comment: @D-Nice I know that this has been ask before but can you share 1 or 2 migrations and the schema.rb

Comment: @D-Nice what happens when you do a `rake db:schema:dump`?  can you check if that would create a schema with indices?

Comment: Try copy pasting migration files in a fresh application and generate schema.rb

Answer (score 2):

In  Rails 3 indexes are not displayed in `schema.rb` file.

Given below is screenshot of shema dump from rails 3 documentation. No indexes are shown.

[image: This is screenshot of schem file from rails documentation]

I have tried to install Rails 3 with Postgres, Rails 3 with Mysql and Rails 3 and SQLite. All the indexes are added to database but you cannot see them in `schema.rb`.

There is only one way to show them in `schema.rb` by adding indexes manually to the file Or you can leave your `scehma.rb` without indexes. All the indexes are added to database when we run `rake db:migrate`. And if you want you can upgrade to rails 4 or above and you will never face this problem.